# FreeRtos only one task is running

Tags: c, embedded, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, freertos

There is only one task is running which is the receiver task with the highest priority, the others don't run unless I use `xtaskdelay` which is a requirement not to be used in my assignment

The code creates 4 timers that control 4 semaphores with which the tasks will work when they take the semaphore. There are 3 sender tasks and 1 receiver, the sender sends to the queue that was created (first 2 senders are of same priority while the third is of higher priority) in a random period of time that is passed to the timer randomly using the random function. after the code reaches 1000 msgs, it resets with the bounds for the timer to send being higher, it goes through this for 6 cycles then it shuts down and stops the scheduler and prints game over the msg to be sent is "time is XYZ" where XYZ is the system time in ticks

```
/*
 * This file is part of the µOS++ distribution.
 *   (https://github.com/micro-os-plus)
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Liviu Ionescu.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
 * sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom
 * the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "diag/trace.h"
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION 1

/* Kernel includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "timers.h"
#include "semphr.h"
#include "projdefs.h"
#include "event_groups.h"
#include "portable.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "croutine.h"
#include "deprecated_definitions.h"
#include "mpu_prototypes.h"
#include "mpu_wrappers.h"
#include "StackMacros.h"
#include <time.h>
#define CCM_RAM __attribute__((section(".ccmram")))
int NumberOfSent1=0;
int NumberOfSent2=0;
int NumberOfSent3=0;
int NumberOfBlocked1=0;
int NumberOfBlocked2=0;
int NumberOfBlocked3=0;
int NumberOfReceived=0;
int Average_sent1=0;
int Average_sent2=0;
int Average_sent3=0;
int Average_blocked1=0;
int Average_blocked2=0;
int Average_blocked3=0;
int TotalTime1=0;
int TotalTime2=0;
int TotalTime3=0;
int Timer1Rand;
int Timer2Rand;
int Timer3Rand;
int UpperBound=150;
int LowerBound=50;
int TimeTask1=0;
int TimeTask2=0;
int TimeTask3=0;
short AverageTime1=0;
short AverageTime2=0;
short AverageTime3=0;
int counterForCycle=0;
char tickcount_converted[10];
char Message[30]="Time is ";
char Buffer[32];
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore1;
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore2;
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore3;
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore4;
QueueHandle_t GlobalQueue;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
 * The LED timer callback function.  This does nothing but switch the red LED
 * off.
 */

static void Timer1Callback( TimerHandle_t xTimer );
static void Timer2Callback( TimerHandle_t xTimer );
static void Timer3Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer);
void Timer4Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer);
static void Sender1(void);
static void Sender2(void);
static void Sender3(void);
void Receiver(void);

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* The LED software timer.  This uses vLEDTimerCallback() as its callback
 * function.
 */
static TimerHandle_t xTimer1;
static TimerHandle_t xTimer2;
static TimerHandle_t xTimer3;
static TimerHandle_t xTimer4;
TaskHandle_t Task1H;
TaskHandle_t Task2H;
TaskHandle_t Task3H;
TaskHandle_t Task4H;

BaseType_t Task1;
BaseType_t Task2;
BaseType_t Task3;
BaseType_t Task4;
BaseType_t xTimer1Started, xTimer2Started,xTimer3Started,xTimer4Started;

// ----- main() ---------------------------------------------------------------


#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-declarations"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreturn-type"

int
main()
{
    // Add your code here.
    srand(time(NULL));
    xSemaphore1=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphore2=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphore3=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphore4=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    xSemaphoreGive(xSemaphore4);
    GlobalQueue=xQueueCreate(10,32);
    Timer1Rand=(rand() % (150 - 50 + 1)) + 50;
    Timer2Rand=(rand() % (150 - 50 + 1)) + 50;
    Timer3Rand=(rand() % (150 - 50 + 1)) + 50;
    xTimer1 = xTimerCreate( "Timer1", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer1Rand) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 0, Timer1Callback);
    xTimer2 = xTimerCreate( "Timer2", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer2Rand) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 1, Timer2Callback);
    xTimer3 = xTimerCreate( "Timer3", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer3Rand) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 2, Timer3Callback);
    xTimer4 = xTimerCreate( "Timer4", ( pdMS_TO_TICKS(100) ), pdTRUE, ( void * ) 3, Timer4Callback);
    Task1 = xTaskCreate(Sender1,"Sender1",1024,(void *)1,0,&Task1H);
    Task2 = xTaskCreate(Sender2,"Sender2",1024,(void *)2,0,&Task2H);
    Task3 = xTaskCreate(Sender3,"Sender3",1024,(void *)3,1,&Task3H);
    Task4 = xTaskCreate(Receiver,"Receiver",1024,(void *)4,2,&Task4H);
    if( ( xTimer1 != NULL ) && ( xTimer2 != NULL )&& ( xTimer3 != NULL )&& ( xTimer4 != NULL ) )
    {
        xTimer1Started = xTimerStart( xTimer1, 0 );
        xTimer2Started = xTimerStart( xTimer2, 0 );
        xTimer3Started = xTimerStart( xTimer3, 0 );
        xTimer4Started = xTimerStart( xTimer4, 0 );
    }
//  if( xTimer1 != NULL ) xTimer1Started = xTimerStart( xTimer1, 0 );
    if( xTimer1Started == pdPASS && xTimer2Started == pdPASS&& xTimer3Started == pdPASS&& xTimer4Started == pdPASS)
    {
        vTaskStartScheduler();
    }
//  if( xTimer1Started == pdPASS)vTaskStartScheduler();

    return 0;
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void Timer1Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore1 );
    //srand(time());
    Timer1Rand=(rand() % (UpperBound - LowerBound + 1)) + LowerBound;
//  vTaskResume(Task1H);
    //printf("A%d\n",Timer2Rand);


}
static void Timer2Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore2 );
    //srand(time());
    Timer2Rand=(rand() % (UpperBound - LowerBound + 1)) + LowerBound;
    //printf("B%d\n",Timer2Rand);
//  vTaskResume(Task2H);


}
static void Timer3Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore3 );
    //srand(time());
    Timer3Rand=(rand() % (UpperBound - LowerBound + 1)) + LowerBound;
    //printf("C%d\n",Timer3Rand);
   //vTaskResume(Task3H);


}
void Timer4Callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer){
    xSemaphoreGive( xSemaphore4 );

}
static void Sender1(void){

    while(1){
        if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore1, 0 ) == pdTRUE){
            TotalTime1+=Timer1Rand;
            TimeTask1=xTaskGetTickCount();
            //printf("A%d\n",TimeTask1);
            itoa(TimeTask1,tickcount_converted,10);
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                    Message[8+i]=tickcount_converted[i];
                    }
            //printf("A%s\n",Message);

    if(xQueueSend(GlobalQueue,&Message,0)==pdTRUE){
        NumberOfSent1++;}
    else NumberOfBlocked1++;
    //printf("A%d\n",NumberOfSent1);
    //printf("AQ%d\n",NumberOfBlocked1);

    //vTaskDelay( pdMS_TO_TICKS(10) );
//  vTaskSuspend(Task1H);
    xTimerChangePeriod(xTimer1,pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer1Rand),0);

        }}
}

static void Sender2(void){

    while(1){
        if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore2, 0 ) == pdTRUE){
            TotalTime2+=Timer2Rand;
            TimeTask2=xTaskGetTickCount();
            itoa(TimeTask2,tickcount_converted,10);
                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                                Message[8+i]=tickcount_converted[i];
                                }
            if(xQueueSend(GlobalQueue,&Message,0)==pdTRUE){
                    NumberOfSent2++;}
                else NumberOfBlocked2++;
            //vTaskDelay( pdMS_TO_TICKS(10) );
            //printf("B%d\n",NumberOfSent2);
//          vTaskSuspend(Task2H);
            xTimerChangePeriod(xTimer2,pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer2Rand),0);

    }}

}
static void Sender3(void){
    while(1){

        if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore3, 0 ) == pdTRUE){
            TotalTime3+=Timer3Rand;
            TimeTask3=xTaskGetTickCount();
            itoa(TimeTask3,tickcount_converted,10);
                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                                Message[8+i]=tickcount_converted[i];
                                }
        if(xQueueSend(GlobalQueue,&Message,0)==pdTRUE){
                NumberOfSent3++;}
            else NumberOfBlocked3++;
        printf("C%d\n",NumberOfSent3);
//      vTaskSuspend(Task3H);
        xTimerChangePeriod(xTimer3,pdMS_TO_TICKS(Timer3Rand),0);

//      vTaskDelay( pdMS_TO_TICKS(10) );
}

        }

}
void Receiver(void){

    while(1){
    if( xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphore4, 0 ) == pdTRUE){
        if(NumberOfReceived==1000){
            AverageTime1=TotalTime1/(NumberOfSent1+NumberOfBlocked1);
            AverageTime2=TotalTime2/(NumberOfSent2+NumberOfBlocked2);
            AverageTime3=TotalTime3/(NumberOfSent3+NumberOfBlocked3);
            printf("NumberOfSent1 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfSent1);
            printf("NumberOfBlocked1 in cycle %d= %d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfBlocked1);
            printf("Average 1 in cycle %d :%d\n",counterForCycle,AverageTime1);
            printf("NumberOfSent2 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfSent2);
            printf("NumberOfBlocked2 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfBlocked2);
            printf("AverageTime2 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,AverageTime2);
            printf("NumberOfSent3 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfSent3);
            printf("NumberOfBlocked3 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfBlocked3);
            printf("AverageTime3 in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,AverageTime3);
            printf("NumberOfReceived in cycle %d =%d\n",counterForCycle,NumberOfReceived);
            xQueueReset(GlobalQueue);
            counterForCycle++;
            TotalTime1=0;
            TotalTime2=0;
            TotalTime3=0;
            NumberOfSent1=0;
            NumberOfSent2=0;
            NumberOfSent3=0;
            NumberOfBlocked1=0;
            NumberOfBlocked2=0;
            NumberOfBlocked3=0;
            NumberOfReceived=0;
            UpperBound+=50;
            LowerBound+=30;

        }
        if(UpperBound>400){
            xTimerDelete(xTimer1,0);
            xTimerDelete(xTimer2,0);
            xTimerDelete(xTimer3,0);
            xTimerDelete(xTimer4,0);
            trace_puts("Game Over");
             vTaskEndScheduler();

        }
    if(xQueueReceive(GlobalQueue,Buffer,0)==pdTRUE){
        NumberOfReceived++;
    }
   //printf("D%d\n",NumberOfReceived);
//  vTaskSuspend(Task4H);

//
    //printf("t%d\n",NumberOfReceived);
    xTimerChangePeriod(xTimer4,pdMS_TO_TICKS(100),0);

//  vTaskDelay( pdMS_TO_TICKS(10) );

    }

}}
void vApplicationMallocFailedHook( void )
{
    /* Called if a call to pvPortMalloc() fails because there is insufficient
    free memory available in the FreeRTOS heap.  pvPortMalloc() is called
    internally by FreeRTOS API functions that create tasks, queues, software
    timers, and semaphores.  The size of the FreeRTOS heap is set by the
    configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE configuration constant in FreeRTOSConfig.h. */
    for( ;; );
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

void vApplicationStackOverflowHook( TaskHandle_t pxTask, char *pcTaskName )
{
    ( void ) pcTaskName;
    ( void ) pxTask;

    /* Run time stack overflow checking is performed if
    configconfigCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW is defined to 1 or 2.  This hook
    function is called if a stack overflow is detected. */
    for( ;; );
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

void vApplicationIdleHook( void )
{
volatile size_t xFreeStackSpace;

    /* This function is called on each cycle of the idle task.  In this case it
    does nothing useful, other than report the amout of FreeRTOS heap that
    remains unallocated. */
    xFreeStackSpace = xPortGetFreeHeapSize();

    if( xFreeStackSpace > 100 )
    {
        /* By now, the kernel has allocated everything it is going to, so
        if there is a lot of heap remaining unallocated then
        the value of configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE in FreeRTOSConfig.h can be
        reduced accordingly. */
    }
}

void vApplicationTickHook(void) {
}

StaticTask_t xIdleTaskTCB CCM_RAM;
StackType_t uxIdleTaskStack[configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE] CCM_RAM;

void vApplicationGetIdleTaskMemory(StaticTask_t **ppxIdleTaskTCBBuffer, StackType_t **ppxIdleTaskStackBuffer, uint32_t *pulIdleTaskStackSize) {
  /* Pass out a pointer to the StaticTask_t structure in which the Idle task's
  state will be stored. */
  *ppxIdleTaskTCBBuffer = &xIdleTaskTCB;

  /* Pass out the array that will be used as the Idle task's stack. */
  *ppxIdleTaskStackBuffer = uxIdleTaskStack;

  /* Pass out the size of the array pointed to by *ppxIdleTaskStackBuffer.
  Note that, as the array is necessarily of type StackType_t,
  configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE is specified in words, not bytes. */
  *pulIdleTaskStackSize = configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE;
}

static StaticTask_t xTimerTaskTCB CCM_RAM;
static StackType_t uxTimerTaskStack[configTIMER_TASK_STACK_DEPTH] CCM_RAM;

/* configUSE_STATIC_ALLOCATION and configUSE_TIMERS are both set to 1, so the
application must provide an implementation of vApplicationGetTimerTaskMemory()
to provide the memory that is used by the Timer service task. */
void vApplicationGetTimerTaskMemory(StaticTask_t **ppxTimerTaskTCBBuffer, StackType_t **ppxTimerTaskStackBuffer, uint32_t *pulTimerTaskStackSize) {
  *ppxTimerTaskTCBBuffer = &xTimerTaskTCB;
  *ppxTimerTaskStackBuffer = uxTimerTaskStack;
  *pulTimerTaskStackSize = configTIMER_TASK_STACK_DEPTH;
}
```

I expected all tasks to work but only one is the problem is that only one task is working and the others aren't which is the receiver task that has the highest priority(2) and no other tasks work not even the timer is called. If any one of you has a solution to this problem I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Software timers work in the task context so they will not work if the task is not running.
2. freeRTOS by default does not have round-robin scheduling (it is REAL TIME OS) unless you enable it in the config. You need to pass the control to the scheduler (and it is why vTaskDelay switches the tasks). When task is blocked waiting for a semaphore or queue, another task can be run. You always have 0 as the wait time which prevents OS from switching.
3. You need to learn how to use synchronization mechanisms - semaphores are not flags which have to be checked in the loop.

Comment: following what you said , i gave a blocking time for semaphore take to 10 ticks and it worked but the task of higher priority is sending the same msgs as the other 2